# Laravel Auth::attempt failing each time

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I have created a test user on my `laravel` app. The details are

user: joe@gmail.com pass: 123456

When I go through the registration process everything works as expected and an entry is made into the `users table` of the `database`

Once this is finished I redirect the `user` to the dashboard.

```
public function postCreate(){
        //Rules
        $rules = array(
        'fname'=>'required|alpha|min:2',
        'lname'=>'required|alpha|min:2',
        'email'=>'required|email|unique:users',
        'password'=>'required|alpha_num|between:6,12|confirmed',
        'password_confirmation'=>'required|alpha_num|between:6,12'
        );
        
        $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules);
        if($validator->passes()){
            //Save in DB - Success
            $user = new User;
            $user->fname = Input::get('fname'); //Get the details of form
            $user->lname = Input::get('lname');
            $user->email = Input::get('email');
            $user->password = Hash::make(Input::get('password'));//Encrypt the password
            $user->save();
            return Redirect::to('/books')->with('Thank you for Registering!');
        }else{
            //Display error - Failed
            return Redirect::to('/')->with('message', 'The Following Errors occurred')->withErrors($validator)->withInput();
        }
    }
```

I then navigate back to the landing page and attempt to log in using the credentials above and I keep getting told that `Auth::attempt()` is failing hence my user cannot log into the application.

```
public function login(){
        if(Auth::attempt(array('email'=>Input::get('email'), 'password'=>Input::get('password')))){
            //Login Success
            echo "Success"; die();
            return Redirect::to('/books');
        }else{
            //Login failed
            echo "Fail"; die();
            return Redirect::to('/')->with('message', 'Your username/password combination was incorrect')->withInput();
        }
    }
```

Does anyone know why this is happening? This is the `Schema` for my `users` table:

```
Schema::create('users', function($table){ 
            $table->increments('id'); 
            $table->integer('type')->unsigned(); 
            $table->string('fname', 255); 
            $table->string('lname', 255); 
            $table->string('email')->unique(); 
            $table->string('password', 60); 
            $table->string('school', 255); 
            $table->string('address_1', 255); 
            $table->string('address_2', 255); 
            $table->string('address_3', 255); 
            $table->string('address_4', 255);
            $table->string('remember_token', 100);
            $table->timestamps(); 
        });
```

Any help is much appreciated.

'View for Login':

```
<div class="page-header">
    <h1>Home page</h1>
</div>

<!-- Register Form -->
<form   action="{{ action('UsersController@postCreate') }}" method="post" role="form">
    <h2 class="form-signup-heading">Register</h2>
    <!-- Display Errors -->
    <ul>
        @foreach($errors->all() as $error)
            <li>{{ $error }}</li>
        @endforeach
    </ul>

    <!-- First Name -->
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>First Name</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="fname" /> 
    </div>
    <!-- Last Name -->
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Last Name</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="lname" /> 
    </div>
    <!-- Email -->
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Email</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="email" /> 
    </div>
    <!-- Password-->
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Password</label>
        <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" />  
    </div>
    <!-- Confirm Password -->
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Confirm Password</label>
        <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password_confirmation" /> 
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Register" class="btn btn-primary"/>
</form>

<!-- Login Form -->
<form   action="{{ action('UsersController@login') }}" method="post" role="form">
    <h2 class="form-signup-heading">Login</h2>
    <!-- Email -->
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Email</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="email" /> 
    </div>
    <!-- Password-->
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Password</label>
        <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" />  
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Login" class="btn btn-primary"/>
</form>
```

Comment: I just used the register form

Comment: sorry I saw that after I commented.

Comment: Can you show us the view for the login? In your method `login`, if you place a `dd(Input::all())`, do you have the expected values?

Comment: also, does your User model implement `Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface` ?

Comment: @watcher yes it does, I am using the default one created by `Laravel` and @milz that returned the expected values, also provided code in question

Comment: Everything seems ok and works. Can you check that the file `app/config/auth.php` have the key-pairs: `'driver' => 'eloquent',`, `'model' => 'User',` and `'table' => 'users',` ?

Comment: In `app/config/session.php`, which driver are you using?

Comment: Your problem is that user is not saved in the DB I suppose. You have non nullable fields that are not filled, so `$user->save()` probably returns false/throws error. Check if anything was saved in the db first.

Comment: I had a similar situation, in my case for some strange reason I am able to authenticate only with `database` as `driver` in `config/auth.php`, instead of `eloquent`.

Comment: Do you work with a debugger? If not, then take the necessary time and set up an environment with a debugger, you will not regret it. Since the source code of Laravel is available, you will also be able to step into the Laravel code if necessary.

Comment: Are you doing any mutators or accessors in your user model? Can you post your user model?

Comment: Can you please confirm the exact version of PHP and Laravel you are running?

Comment: @Javacadabra did my answer below help? Are you able to answer the two questions above?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Can you run this function below - and tell me where the error occurs? It will diagnose the problem:

```
public function testLogin()
{
     $user = new User;
     $user->fname = 'joe';
     $user->lname = 'joe';
     $user->email = 'joe@gmail.com';
     $user->password = Hash::make('123456');

     if ( ! ($user->save()))
     {
         dd('user is not being saved to database properly - this is the problem');          
     }

     if ( ! (Hash::check('123456', Hash::make('123456'))))
     {
         dd('hashing of password is not working correctly - this is the problem');          
     }

     if ( ! (Auth::attempt(array('email' => 'joe@gmail.com', 'password' => '123456'))))
     {
         dd('storage of user password is not working correctly - this is the problem');          
     }

     else
     {
         dd('everything is working when the correct data is supplied - so the problem is related to your forms and the data being passed to the function');
     }
}
```

Edit: one thought - are you sure the user is being *correctly* saved in the database? Have you tried to 'empty/delete' your database and try your code again? In your current code, it will fail if you keep registering with joe@gmail.com - because it is unique. But you dont catch the error anywhere. So empty the database and try again...

Edit 2: [I found another question you posted with the same problem](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59515/discussion-between-drmarvelous-and-javacadabra) - and in there you mentioned that the following code is your user model?

```
use Illuminate\Auth\UserTrait; 
use Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface; 
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableTrait; 
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableInterface; 

class User extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface { 

use UserTrait, RemindableTrait; 

/** 
* The database table used by the model. 
* 
* @var string 
*/ 
protected $table = 'users'; 

/** 
* The attributes excluded from the model's JSON form. 
* 
* @var array 
*/ 
protected $hidden = array('password'); 

public function getAuthIdentifier() { 

} 

public function getAuthPassword() { 
} 

public function getRememberToken() { 

} 

public function getRememberTokenName() { 

} 

public function getReminderEmail() { 

} 

public function setRememberToken($value) { 

} 
}
```

Is that EXACTLY your current user model? Because if so - it is wrong - none of those functions should be blank.

This is what a CORRECT user model should look like for Laravel 4.2

```
use Illuminate\Auth\UserTrait;
use Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableTrait;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableInterface;

class User extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {

    use UserTrait, RemindableTrait;

    /**
     * The database table used by the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'users';

    /**
     * The attributes excluded from the model's JSON form.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = array('password', 'remember_token');

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You would make sure about:

- your model:

mine looks like:

```
use Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableInterface;

class User extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {

        protected $table = 'users';

        protected $hidden = array('password');

        public function getAuthIdentifier()
        {
            Return $this->getKey ();
        }
        public function getAuthPassword()
        {
            return $this->password;
        }
    }
```

- make sure your app/config/auth.php is configured correctly
- make sure app/config/app.php has service provider

> 'Illuminate\Auth\AuthServiceProvider',

- Make sure your controller class has auth. before writing class you have used Auth  (I mean include Auth class)

That all could make Auth doesn't work well

Comment: Helpful answer but not what I was looking for, thank you though

Answer (score 2):

With password hashing enabled, the `User` model must override these methods:

```
public function getAuthIdentifierName()
{
    return 'email';
}

public function getAuthIdentifier()
{
    return request()->get('email');
}

public function getAuthPassword()
{
    return Hash::make(request()->get('password'));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What is the value for `strlen(Hash::make(Input::get('password')))`? If it is greater than 60, then this would cause the authentication to fail each time, as the stored password is not the full hash.

Comment: In Laravel the hash output is fixed at 60

Answer (score -1):

Good day, here is what I discovered when I encountered the same error: A simple string compare will reveal that the two hashing methods produce two different hashed values.

```
echo strcmp(Hash::make('password'),bcrypt('password'));
```

My assumption is that `Auth::attempt([])` uses `bcrypt()` to hash out passwords which produces a different value to what you used `Hash:make()`.

Comment: Your assumption is wrong: values are hashed using a random salt so should never be the same. And this is a 7.5 year old question asking about an ancient version of Laravel.